# how to add colored lines with opencv after covnersion from grayscale to color (vispy)

Tags: python, opencv, grayscale, qtwidgets, vispy

I have the following problem. I need to import grayscale images and add some colored lines in the image at distinct positions (prefered colors are red or blue because they are visible)
I thought of converting the photo to rgb and then add line.
shape before the conversion is a 2d array, after conversion 3d

my problem is:

- if I do this independently with a script , i get the colored line without any problems
- if i integrate it to this script. however whatever I do the line is either black or white (I tried different colors) I specifically checked that when emitting the shape is still a 3d array

the point of this script is to show different images according to a frequence. when getting the image we add certain colored lines then we show them. for simplicity here i just send the same image over and over. the grayscale image should stay have the same characterstics visually. the only colored pixels are the added lines.

I keep thinking there is something wrong with the vispy when showing the image. because if we do this with only cv2 we get the right color.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from vispy import scene
from PySide2.QtCore import QMetaObject
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import numpy as np
import time
import imageio as iio
import cv2

class CameraThread(QtCore.QThread):
    new_image = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
            try:
                while True:
                    frame = iio.imread(my_image)
                    print("shape before conversion: ", frame.data.shape)
                    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
                    print("shape after conversion: ", frame.data.shape)
                    cv2.line(frame, pt1=(100, 300), pt2=(400, 300), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=10)

                    self.new_image.emit(frame.data)
                    time.sleep(3.0)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"problem: {e}")
            finally:
                print('end!')


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 400)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # OpenGL drawing surface
        self.canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive')
        self.canvas.create_native()
        self.canvas.native.setParent(self)


        self.setWindowTitle('MyApp')


        self.view = self.canvas.central_widget.add_view()

        self.view.bgcolor = '#ffffff'   # set the canvas to a white background

        self.image = scene.visuals.Image(np.zeros((1, 1, 1)),
                                         interpolation='nearest',
                                         parent= self.view.scene,
                                         cmap='grays',
                                         clim=(0, 2 ** 8 - 1))


        self.view.camera = scene.PanZoomCamera(aspect=1)
        self.view.camera.flip = (0, 1, 0)
        self.view.camera.set_range()
        self.view.camera.zoom(1000, (0, 0))

        self._camera_runner = CameraThread(parent=self)
        self._camera_runner.new_image.connect(self.new_image, type=QtCore.Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
        self._camera_runner.start()


    @QtCore.Slot(object)
    def new_image(self, img):
        try:
            print("shape when emitting: ", img.shape)
            self.image.set_data(img)
            self.image.update()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"problem sending image: {e}")

def main():
    import ctypes
    ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID('my_gui')

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer thanks to the vispy forum. for the ones that are interested
the whole problem was in the initialization of the image

one needed to put a correct parameter `np.zeros(1, 1, 3)`

if it s false from the very beginning it will never update automatically.